# Proving an integrable function on $[a,b]$ is constant a.e.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f \in L^1[a,b]$. Assume that $\lim_{h \to 0} \int_a^b \frac{1}{h}|f(x+h)-f(x)|\,dx =0$. I'm trying to show that there exists a constant $c$ such that $f(x) = c$ for a.e. $x \in (a, b)$. Given that only $f$ is integrable, I tried using dominated convergence theorem on this integral to try to pull the limit into the integral but I don't think that approach works. I'd appreciate any help on how to go about proving this.